# Удалить опросник из чата бота на AIOGRAM

Tags: python, aiogram

вопрос, как удалить из чата бота опросник?
Создаю опросник:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message):
    await message.answer_poll(question='Опросник',
                              options=['Ответ_1', 'Ответ_2', 'Ответ_3'],
                              type='quiz',
                              correct_option_id=1,
                              is_anonymous=False)
```

Отлавливаю ответ пользователей:

```
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def print_poll(quiz_answer: types.PollAnswer):
    logging.info(f'Новый ответ в опросник: id ответа: {quiz_answer.option_ids[0]}, ответ ответил: {quiz_answer.user.username}, его id: {quiz_answer.user.id}')
    await bot.send_message(quiz_answer.user.id, f'Спасибо за Ваше участие в опросе! Ваше мнение очень важно для нас и обязательно будет учтено!')
```

Хотел бы удалять опросник из чата тех, кто проголосовал, пробовал реализовать по принципу удаления предыдущего сообщения из чата, через:

```
await bot.delete_message(quiz_answer.user.id, message_id=quiz_answer.poll_id - 1)
```

Не работает. Без -1 тоже не работает, судя по всему message.chat_id и poll_id не взаимозаменяемые вещи. Как можно реализовать удаление опросника из чата?